# Is it possible to pay the ubuntu one storage with PayPal?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I just wanted to purchase 20GB of space for my ubuntu one account. But I have no creditcard, just a paypal account and online-banking. What can I do now? Will it be possible to pay through PayPal? I mean, in the ubuntu one music store PayPal is accepted... hmm.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to use PayPal to buy Ubuntu One services:

**first launch your ubuntu-one control panel...**

[image]

**click the link shown ... and login to your website account...**

[image]

**click the add storage button...**

[image]

**select how much storage addons and billing...**

[image]

**select paypal when requested and login to your paypal to buy**