# Ubuntu One - Purchase storage

Tags: ubuntu-one, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to pay the ubuntu one storage with PayPal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19327/is-it-possible-to-pay-the-ubuntu-one-storage-with-paypal)

2 years ago Ubuntu said we will be able to purchase Ubuntu One storage via PayPal sometime. Does anyone know what's the progress?
Yesterday I tried to buy some Gigabytes but there is always a `Payment Failure`. Am I the only one who's affected or is this a general known problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem you are seeing is a general one.  If you are having trouble, I would suggest using the contact form so that someone can have a look at what is going wrong with your transactions:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Comment: U1 gave me 20 GB storage for free until end of august. My credit cards have security mechanisms and Ubuntu doesn't support it.